# Set Qlabel width

Tags: qt, label, size

I'm trying to make a ratio between 2 numbers (likes & dislikes).

The result is a number in percent. Then I want to make the width from the label equal that percent.

So If there are 100 likes and 1 dislike. I want to make the dislike label 1 percent the width of the like bar. So basically like the youtube rating system.

Example image: 
[image]

But I don't see any function to set the width of the label.
So how do I need to do this, anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`QLabel::setFixedWidth(int)`.  Though to make it more flexible (don't have to worry about layouts changing things), I would subclass `QWidget`, add slots for the two numbers, and reimplement `paintEvent(..)` to draw the two sections.

Comment: +1 - A custom `QWidget` with `paintEvent()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, i`m just using resize() method.
For example my widget, implemented from QLabel:

> `BenchItem *itm=static_cast<BenchItem*>(widget);`
>     `itm->resize(this->width(),itm->height());`

i don`t need change height so it uses itself height, but width should change due to parents width().

Answer (score 1):

I have used setGeometry() method to set the QLabel width dynamically.
I have qlabel in Form Ui.

```
ui->qlabel->setGeometry(x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at QT documentation, this element can only contain

*"Plain text, Rich text, A pixmap, A movie, A number, or Nothing"*

where the most promising of these, "pixmap", seems not to have the image manipulation functionality you would need, instead being more about displaying images:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html

Instead, I'd suggest looking into more lightweight solutions for your bar graph problem, like CSS. Here's a way to do this using two div elements:

http://www.1080degrees.net/archive/journal/simple_css_bar_graph/

If you prefer displaying an image after all, and have GD libraries enabled, perhaps have a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php

Comment: First link seems to be broken, second link points to a php function?

Comment: Well, it wasn't when I posted this over 16 months ago!

Comment: Yes, that's why I commented,was hoping you'd expand on what was in the link since it's broken now.